# WordPress Cron Job in Bookly Plugin

Tags: wordpress, cron

Hell, Friends. I am using [WordPress Bookly Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bookly-responsive-appointment-booking-tool/) . I want to send emails to customers daily using cron. Plugin is aksing this words to me
"

> **To send scheduled notifications please execute the following script hourly with your cron: php -f
>   C:\wamp\www\multan-academy\wp-content\plugins\bookly-responsive-appointment-booking-tool\lib\utils\send_notifications_cron.php
>   "**

. Here, is the code for that file. What should I include or call here.

```
define('SHORTINIT', true);

/**
 * Class Notifications
 */

class Notifications{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }
}
$notifications = new Notifications();
```

Comment: Have you searched SO for "cron"?

Comment: That's "StackOverflow".  As explained in the introductory documentation, we expect you to research your question before posting here.